# Issues with apt repositories in Kali Linux, errors when updating

Tags: apt, kali-linux

This shows every time I run `sudo apt update`. Is it an issue?

[image]

Comment: Also, please don't post pictures of text. We can't copy and paste from images. Instead, copy the text and paste it into your question, and use the "code formatting" (`{ }`) button.

Comment: It's telling you repeatedly to read the man pages for `apt-secure` and `apt-key` - did you do that?   Also, if you can't interpret what apt is saying above then you're a beginner and kali linux is not for beginners.

Answer (score 3):

You're using Ubuntu and Debian buster repos in Kali. Don't do that; that's not supposed to work, and it breaks. (whoever recommended you do that did not understand what they recommended) If you want what is in that repo, or simply a general purpose Linux system for daily usage, instead of one tailored towards **Linux experts** who do nothing but **penetration testing** with it, use Ubuntu itself. That's not what I say, that's what [Kali says themselves](https://www.kali.org/docs/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux/)!

> Is this a issue?

Yes, but not in the way you think it is: You're trying to install software built for a different operating system with different libraries. Your apt is stopping you (not because it recognizes that, but because you haven't installed the matching keyring. Good thing.)

> How do I resolve it?

Don't use Kali, if you want to use third-party debian or Ubuntu software. Use debian or ubuntu. You certainly shouldn't be installing sublime text on a special-purpose pentesting system, that just makes no sense. Nutty is a network analysis tool, and I can see why you'd want that on your Kali installation. Well, you'll have to build it then yourself.

It's not hard, since there's already a Ubuntu package, but essentially, follow the [Kali development guide on packaging](https://www.kali.org/docs/development/setting-up-packaging-system/).
You'd use your main Linux (e.g. Ubuntu, Debian) to set up a development Kali VM.